# Merging two SQL tables with key conflicts

Tags: mysql, merge

I am trying to merge (union) two tables with the same structure. In a known block of rows, the primary key (an auto_increment integer) is in use in both tables for different data. Let's say it's the rows with primary keys 2000-2150. What is the best way to renumber these records in table B to unused values (say, in the range above 3000), so that the merge can proceed without conflicts? Should I just UPDATE them in place (say, by adding 1000 to each ID in that range), or are there better ways?

Notes:

1. All references to this table are declared `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, so that I can safely renumber them without consequences.
2. The rest of the merge I can handle. Both tables contain useful data, and when a key outside that range is repeated, I will keep the version in Table A.

Comment: If you could, please provide the query you are attempting now so that we have something to work off of. However as a short answer, in your select of `Table B` you could: `select Id + 3000, col2, col3, col4 from TableB`. - That is, if the `Id` column is numeric.

Comment: I don't have a query yet-- I'm unsure which approach to take. I thought about doing an `UPDATE` to add 1000 to each id in the block, but I thought I'd ask if there is a more appropriate approach.

Comment: Ok, I'll just move my comment to an answer then and maybe add a few more thoughts to it.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out at all? It isn't likely that there will be anything more specific, unfortunately... =(

Comment: Not especially... I'm checking now, but I'll have to take a closer look when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the numbers to the negative of the number would work. There would be no chance of a collision now or in the future.

Comment: Thanks-- I can think of many mappings that will resolve the collision (I'd rather add 1000). I guess my question is, do I just `UPDATE` this block of IDs, or are there better methods/approaches available for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Move from comment to answer.

If you could, please provide the query you are attempting now so that we have something to work off of. However as a short answer...

In your select of Table B you could:

```
select Id, col2, col3, col4
from TableA
union all
select Id + 3000, col2, col3, col4 
from TableB;
```

That is, if the Id column is numeric.

One thing to note, if you are then going to try to insert those records into `Table A`, you will need to disable the auto-sequencing.

Another option, if you are going to insert the records into `Table A` from `Table B`, setting aside the possible problems of orphaned child records from `Table B`, you could omit the `Id` column from `Table B` on a `SELECT INTO TableA...` as when you do the insert, a new `Id` value will be generated with the auto-increment id.

For the issue of orphaned child records, you could also add a new column to `TableA` called `TableBId` that would house the original `Id` from `TableB` which would allow you to still access the old data associated to `TableB.Id`. Another alternative would be a new child table for this same idea. This would prevent you having to alter your `TableA` structure, yet still provide some way to retain access to your old data.

If you had more information on what you are wanting to ultimately do, we could possibly come up with a much better solution, but this should get you started.

Comment: That sounds like good advice over all, but your on the fly approach won't cascade the ID change to related tables... so that's a non-starter. Table A won't be growing anymore, so it's safe to modify.

Comment: Are you planning this to be a one time thing? Are you retiring one of the tables after you perform the merge. or will this be an ongoing, replication-type scenario? As far as the changes to child records, that is what I was talking about by either adding a new column, or ideally, add a new lookup table containing the new Id column as well as the previous, retired tables `Id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the id values that are "duplicated"

```
 SELECT b.id
   FROM b
   JOIN a
     ON b.id = a.id
```

Identify new "id" values

```
SELECT MAX(m.id)
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(ma.id) AS id
           FROM a ma
          UNION ALL
         SELECT MAX(mb.id) AS id
           FROM b mb
       ) m
```

Generate new "unused" id values

```
 SELECT s.id           AS old_id
      , @id := @id + 1 AS new_id 
   FROM ( SELECT b.id
            FROM b
            JOIN a
              ON b.id = a.id
           ORDER BY b.id 
        ) s
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT @id := MAX(ma.id) FROM a ma) i 
 ORDER
    BY s.id
```

Perform update

```
 UPDATE b t
   JOIN ( SELECT r.*
            FROM ( SELECT s.id           AS old_id
                        , @id := @id + 1 AS new_id 
                     FROM ( SELECT b.id
                              FROM b
                              JOIN a
                                ON b.id = a.id
                             ORDER BY b.id 
                          ) s
                   CROSS
                    JOIN ( SELECT @id = MAX(m.id)
                             FROM ( SELECT MAX(ma.id) AS id
                                      FROM a ma
                                     UNION ALL
                                    SELECT MAX(mb.id) AS id
                                      FROM b mb
                                  ) m     
                         ) i 
                   ORDER
                      BY s.id 
                 ) r
        ) q
     ON t.id = q.old_id
    SET t.id = q.new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do it more regularly, try some fancy way like the others describe, if it is a get things done one timer, just do it the easy way and make sure you don't break anything:

- create mysql dump
- disable scripts writing to a and b
- disable auto_increment
- caculate offset (min id from b - max id from a + 1)
- fix entries in b (if cascade works)

  update b set b.id = b.id + offset where b.id in (select id from a)
- fix auto_increment of both tables (set behind last entry)
- enable auto_increment
- enable script that writes to table a
- produce error message in script that tries to write to table b, explaining that data has merged with a (or just use table a there too)
- rename table b to delete_after_2016_05_31_b

erm, what happens to the cascaded data that still points to table b?

this only "moves" duplicates to a new location, also make sure nobody is ever gonna restore deleted data from a backup in the not-duplicate range.

another approach is to go record by record and insert the data into table a and then use mysqllastinsertid to update all entries pointing to the old value.